# Reading Excel file with SQL returns null due to empty column

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am attempting to read in an Excel File from a third party but it falls over and returns null due to empty column.

The file has 50 columns, a blank column and a further 48 columns. I only want the first 50 columns. If I delete or populate the empty column in Excel it works but I need to read 50+ files one after the other, regularly, so opening/deleting/saving isn't an option.

```vb
Function read_excel_file(StrPath, StrFile, ByRef TotalFileArray() As Variant)

Dim ReadFileArray() As Variant

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & StrPath & StrFile & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""
'This assumes the Excel file contains column headers -- HDR=Yes


 'Routine to get unknown sheet name
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & StrPath & StrFile & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""
    
    conn.Open
    Set bs = conn.OpenSchema(20) ' 20 = adSchemaTables
    Do Until bs.EOF = True
        'Debug.Print bs.Fields!Table_Name.Value
        SheetName = bs.Fields!Table_Name.Value
        bs.MoveNext
    Loop
    bs.Close: conn.Close
    Set bs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

Dim sql As String
'sql = "SELECT Meter Id, Date, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00, 03:30, 04:00, 04:30, 05:00, 05:30, 06:00, 06:30, 07:00, 07:30, 08:00, 08:30, 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00, 21:30, 22:00, 22:30, 23:00, 23:30, 24:00:00 FROM [" + SheetName + "]" '

sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "]" '

'Dim rs As Object 'New adodb.Recordset
'Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open sql, connectionString

ReadFileArray() = rs.GetRows 'Puts the data from the recordset into an array
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

I did try using specific requests for the columns I wanted but this still returned null. I attempted a single column but again returned null.

Is there a way around the empty column? Even if reading the file in a different way. (I nearly always read in csv files which are a breeze to get into an array and deal with.)

Picture of source data headers
[image]

Comment: So no error is raised with both SQL statements but NULL is returned?

Comment: Rather than manually opening/deleting/saving/closing the file(s), couldn't you try pre-processing it/them with VBA to delete the offending column instead, before then running your query?

Comment: @Parfait ReadFileArray() is created with the right number of rows and columns, but all are empty. No error is raised.

Comment: @user9601310 Managed to achieve this although now looking clunky. Open file, delete columns, save file.Then read file to get sheet name (I guess I could do this while open). Finally use SQL to load file into array at which point I can grab the cell info with MeterID to enable me to rename the file with the MeterID! All to let some other macro find the data it needs using MeterID as the filename. I guess once I have bothered to open the file properly I may as well just delete the columns, grab the meter ID and save the file!

Comment: @FootSore, admittedly it's a workaround. Presumably you can't get the 3rd party to address the core issue for you?

Comment: @user9601310 No chance of changing file as it comes from an automated system & I can't tell what's wrong. If I open then save it works fine, but if I use it raw it isn't. So have gone with your solution of an alternative route. I'll rewrite the code to open, delete the columns, grab the meter ID and save the file as MeterID.xlsx. There is another macro that comes later and picks up the data by meter ID that works with data from a few sources but is working meter by meter. So this was always just a preprocess for this source. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it up.

Comment: @FootSore, offer gratefully accepted! Posting now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have no choice but to work with the files in the format provided, the best approach/workaround (rather than manually opening/deleting/saving/closing the files individually) would appear to be to pre-process them using VBA to delete the offending column, before then running your query.

Comment: As this was the route chosen I’ve marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Excel worksheet contains columns in first row and you specify `HDR=Yes`, then your first SQL statement would work if you properly enclosed the column names with brackets since they contain special characters like spaces and start with numbers.

```vb
' OPEN CONNECTION WITH HEADERS INDICATED
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & StrPath & StrFile & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""

conn.Open connectionString

' RUN SQL WITH COLUMNS SPECIFIED
sql = "SELECT [Meter Id], [Date]" _
    & "     , [00:30], [01:00], ..., [23:30], [24:00:00]" _
    & " FROM [" + SheetName + "]"

rs.Open sql, connectionString
...
```

In fact, your original attempt *should* have raised an error in attempting to run. Also, the second SQL with `SELECT * FROM` *should* raise an error with empty column since one of the column names is zero length which is an invalid identifier. Therefore, you need to explicitly select columns.

---

After deeper review, it appears your time columns may be in `Custom` format as time values which really are formatted Excel decimal values. Hence, the SQL engine cannot find `[00:30]` column. To fix, convert time value columns into text format.

Consider below subroutine to automate the conversion with [**`Text()`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c). You can then call this VBA sub or function from other main method on each worksheet before any SQL query. Do note there is no such time value as `24:00:00` so this may be already in text format.

```vb
Sub Clean_Time_Columns()
    Dim i As Integer, lastcol As Integer
    Dim tmp_time As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

        For i = 3 To 49    ' LEAVE OUT 24:00:00
            tmp_time = .Cells(1, i).Value
            .Cells(1, i).NumberFormat = "@"
            .Cells(1, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(tmp_time, "HH:MM")
        Next i
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ```sql = "SELECT [Meter Id], [Date], [00:30] FROM [" + SheetName + "]"` ``` gives Run-time error '-2147217904 (8004e10)': No value give for one or more parameters.

Comment: That error indicates one of the fields is not recognized. Please adjust to actuals. In fact, can you post screenshot of upper right corner of data. By the way this answer is for `HDR=Yes` parameter in connection.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the data. I have tried [00:30:00] and [00:30] for a shortened request, and even just [Date]. I really think the blank column is just a no go even if calling specifically. I have worked round it by opening/deleteing columns but it would be faster if I could use the SQL query without this fudge first.

Comment: Ok. So what happens when you use this query with `HDR=Yes` in connection string? I believe your previous attempt used `HDR=No`.

Comment: If I use select [Meter ID], [Date], [00:30] From (or [00:30] then an error: Too few parameters. Expected 3.       If I run with select * from I get a correctly sized array 0-98 & 0-5 but it is all null.

Comment: Have been testing. If I open & save the file in Excel it works fine.with HDR as No/Yes and can even use select * FROM. If I take the file raw it fails. The file is created by a web download so it is possible something isn't straight.

Comment: I see what is happening after re-creating a version of your worksheet, I did run into issues with the time columns. First, I had no issue with `SELECT [Meter Id],  [Date]`. But the 30-min increment column headers were formatted as `Custom` for time values. But Excel actually stores time values as decimal points. So there really is no `[00:30]` identifier, the SQL engine can see. To fix, include a conversion step before querying. See extended answer.

Comment: Totally agree on no such thing as 24:00:00 but it gets used a fair bit in utilities. Consumption from 23:30 (today) to 00:00 (tomorrow) so some systems record it as 24:00:00 (today) or on a line with today’s date. It can be become a nightmare just working when data is for. Toss in DST shifts and it’s a nightmare.

Comment: Despite not being quite the final answer I learnt more from this regarding SQL queries into Excel files. I already plan to re-use lessons learnt on another file where they stick extra columns in that I don’t need from time to time. Huge thanks.